# Unable to delete file after moving in c#

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to delete a file but I am getting error message (access denied) even though I have full permission. Initially my file will be in my root folder. First I am renaming the file and then moving the file to a different folder (outside of root folder) as below.

```
System.IO.File.Move(strPhysicalFolder+ tpfile,strPhysicalFolder+fName);
System.IO.File.Move(strPhysicalFolder + fName, filePath + fName);
System.IO.File.SetAttributes(filePath + fName, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

Now whenever I try to delete the file I am getting an error (access denied). 
Below is my code:

```
string strFileFullPath = srcPath + filename;
if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFileFullPath))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(strFileFullPath);
}
```

`strFileFullPath` contains the path to the file I am not able to delete. Do I need to do anything before deleting (setting attribute)? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what happens if you go to the file in explorer. Can you actually delete it from its new location outside of code?

Comment: Side note but do look up `System.IO.Path.Combine()`

Comment: Not enough information. Are you doing anything between moving and deleting? If so: what. Also: renaming and moving can be done in one step. Also: better use `System.IO.Path.Combine` instad of string concatenation. Are you sure all paths are correct (including path delimiter)?

Comment: Thanks. As per Tom answer it is working. I will put combine now. Thanks

Comment: The question isn't very clear. I can't tell if/how the file you want to delete is related to the Move(). Do you want to delete the original, the target ? For your next question, look at the [mcve] page first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds daft but it will probably be the permissions on the folder.

maybe something like the following:

```
System.IO.File.SetAttributes(strFileFullPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
System.IO.File.Delete(strFileFullPath);
```

Comment: Thank you Tom. This worked. But may i know the reason to set file attribute?

Comment: It was something I found by mistake a while ago, I assume like me you are maybe moving this file somewhere on your `C:\` if this is the case then the file attributes will be elevated and you can't just go in and delete (via your application). as such you will need to change this before you can delete.

Comment: Yes exactly i am moving to c because whenever i keep file in root folder it will be directly accessible to user. So i am moving all files out of root folder.